# htaccess - Simulate a vhost behaviour

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, virtualhost

Hie !

I have nor words neither skills to find answer so i ask here.

I have a dedicated server with no root access (ready to use).
Here is the structure :
 /nothing in the root
 /myportfolio/
 /clients/client1/project1
 /clients/client2/project1...

It was a wonderfull world until a "client3/project1" wanted to use his own URL (project1.client3.com) which it manage himself. I can't do anything with this sub-domain.

By giving my IP adress to this client this sub-domain will point at the server root and as i have no access to the httpd.conf file to put a vhost inside, i am stuck...

Can i have on the server root a htaccess wich act like this :

```
if url = projet1.client3.com
show the clients/client3/projet1 content
```

How to write this ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} project1.client3.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/clients/client3/project1/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks you very much for your answer but i get an error 500. i don't know why... If you have another idea ? thank you

Comment: Can you look in the server logs and see the source of the 500 error?

Comment: no i can't, there is only "access logs" and "ftp logs". Hate this server :) thanks a lot !

Comment: The rule appears to work correctly, so it's not a syntax error. Must be a configuration thing. Can you try with the current rules?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works now, i don't know why i did not make any change. But it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    DocumentRoot path/to/website/public
    AllowOverride All
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: thank you for trying to help unfortunatly i have no access to the root folders.